# All checkbox columns are not selected for row that is added to the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid to which I can dynamically add rows and columns. Each column has a checkbox next to it and checking it makes all checkboxes for that column be selected.

It looks like this:

[image]

Below is my code to add columns by clicking the "Add another column" button.

```
$('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
    myfrom.find('tr').each(function(){
        var trow = $(this);
        var columnName = $('#colorName').val()
        if(trow.index() === 1){
          trow.append('<th > ' + columnName + ' <input type="checkbox" class="colmaster"/>');
        }else if (trow.index() > 1){
            trow.append('<td><input type="checkbox" name="'+columnName+'" class="child" /></td>');
        }
    });
    iter += 1;
});
```

And here is the code for selecting all checkboxes in the column.

```
$('.colmaster').click(function(){
 var idx = $(this).parent().index();
 $('#colorgrid td:nth-child(' + (idx + 1) + ') input.child').prop('checked', this.checked);
})
```

**Question**
For the newly added columns, `justadded` in the screenshot above, when I check the checkbox it doesn't seem to select all checkboxes in that column

Here is a working fiddle for everything: http://jsfiddle.net/y55nn1qx/4/

Comment: Do you really want to use such an old version of jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.colmaster').click` will only bind the event to `.colmaster` elements that exist at the time of running the code. Try something like this:

```
$('#colorgrid').on('click', '.colmaster', function() {
     // insert your .colmaster.click code here
});
```

[Here's the jQuery API reference for `on`.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: That jsfiddle is set up with an antique version of jQuery (1.6 something), pre-`.on()`

Comment: @Pointy Huh, I'm pretty sure that's a mistake on the OP's part while setting up the fiddle. I can't think of any reason why someone would want to use such an old version of jQuery.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for spotting that. I'm able to bump up the version and got this working. I have latest version of jQuery in my actual code for the project.

Comment: @Pointy LOL thanks for making me feel old... calling something "antique" that is 3 years old ;)

Comment: @Mottie well jQuery moves pretty fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('.colmaster').click(function(){` to:

```
$('.colmaster').live('click', function(){ // jQuery < 1.7
```

So that any `.colmaster` added to the DOM after DOM ready can also be included.

**NOTE**

If you upgrade to a modern version of jQuery you would use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.colmaster', function(){ //jQuery 1.7+
```

[jQuery API Documentation | live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)